# Which Ubuntu is oriented to programming and robotics? server, desktop or other distro?

Tags: server, programming, distro-recommendation

Well, rather than a question is an opinion from you, it goes well,
What version of ubuntu is better oriented programming to robotics or anything related to programming languages ​​(like C, perl, c + +, java, etc..?) I have read on other forums that say Ubuntu (desktop) is unstable , EYE I mean when you start playing the system configuration files and goes crazy.
Also not sure if ubuntu server is most convenient for programming, robotics and stuff or if other distros are better for it as mint, fedora, suse, or debian arch, and then based on their experience and knowledge I would like to give their opinions regarding this.

Greetings (:

Answer (score 5):

There "under the hood" difference between ubuntu flavours is very minor. All flavors use the same archive (use the same packages). Each flavor is basically just a set of default installed packages. You can install all flavors concurrently, or switch between them, by adding and removing packages.

So, no, there's no good reason to install "Ubuntu Server" if you are intending to use the machine as a desktop, and vice-versa.

Answer (score 1):

For robotics you would be interested in installing ROS (Robot Operating System). As pointed out, there isn't a big difference between Desktop and Server besides the default packages. Since Desktop is geared to GUI-based applications, it would be better for running robot simulations.

Answer (score 0):

As the other poster said, all of the linux "flavors" are very similar at the core. Some, like puppy linux, are small enough to boot straight from a flash drive, and others, such as ubuntu, offer what you might call an easier to use UI and design, though larger in size. Ubuntu, and other distros I assume, come built in with a python interpreter you can run straight from the terminal. You can also compile and run C/C++ files straight from the terminal, as long as you have the right packages installed, gcc I believe. There are also plenty of IDEs you can install such as Code::Blocks, Eclipse, KDevelop, NetBeans and etc.